# htpasswd для всего сайта кроме определенного url

Tags: .htaccess

Нужно закрыть доступ на весь сайт с помощью htpasswd, но чтобы он оставался открытым для одного URL например site.com/mj

**Нашел способ:**

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/mj" noauth=1

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Private zone. Only for administrator!"
AuthUserFile    .../.htpasswd
Require valid-user

# Here is where we allow/deny
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
```

Comment: вот тут ответ на ваш вопрос. я думаю по-англицки поймете http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865374/http-basic-auth-exclude-single-file

Comment: Да. Все понятно. Но только там открывается доступ для определенного файла, а у меня все запросы редиректятся на index.php
<code>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]
</code>

и mj это не файл или директория

Comment: тогда, я думаю, это нельзя закрыть штатными средствами.  закрывайте в коде

Comment: Способ все-таки есть. Добавил в описание

Comment: Хорошо. Вы можете написать как ответ и пометить принятым, чтобы в будущем было понятно, что это работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нашел способ:**

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "/mj" noauth=1

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Private zone. Only for administrator!"
AuthUserFile    .../.htpasswd
Require valid-user

# Here is where we allow/deny
Order Deny,Allow
Satisfy any
Deny from all
Require valid-user
Allow from env=noauth
```